# data structure to store single parent family tree in react

Tags: reactjs, data-structures

I am trying to design a data structure to store a single parent family tree in react where:

- each family member can have zero or more children
- each family member can have an indefinite number of properties,    e.g. name, gender, favorite color, etc.
- there should not be a limit on the depth of the family tree.

For that, I am using a button and by clicking on that child should me added. But I doubt is my approach correct ? Is there any better approach doing this. All suggestions are welcome.

```
class App extends Component {
  state =  {
    users: [{
      name: "",
      favouriteColor: ""
    }]
  }

  onSubmit = e => { /* submit form logic */ }

  render(){

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={}> Root ( click here to add children ) </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use [react-treebeard](https://github.com/storybooks/react-treebeard) as a starting point. It's built for exactly this purpose. It follows the following structure, though, you can of course add additional properties on as you need–it's fairly extensible:

```
{
  "name": "family",
  "children": [{
    "name": "member",
    "children": []
  }]
}
```

Use that structure in your state and build a button that adds children to the appropriate `children` array at whatever depth you require. I've used this component for trees that had a depth of 5.

The working demo link is broken on that repo but it can be found [here](http://storybooks.github.io/react-treebeard/)